# How to reference instance argument value created with for_each meta-argument in another instance in the same map

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, hcl

**Updated with a more illustrative example.**

My end goal is to have Terraform create instances of a resource generated with the `for_each` meta argument in a *specific sequence*. HCL is known to be a declarative language and when Terraform applies a configuration it can create resources randomly unless you use the `depends_on` argument or refer from one resource (instance) to another. However, the `depends_on` argument does not take values that are "calculated", so I don't know how to use it in modules.

For this reason, in order to force Terraform to create instances of a resource in a specific sequence, I decided to try to make the value of a certain argument in an instance it creates "calculated" based on the values of the same argument from another instance.

Below you can find a more practical example based on using one of the providers, but the question is more general and pertains to Terraform as such.

Let's take a test module that instantiates the `cloudflare_page_rule` resource:

```
# Module is placed to module\main.tf

terraform {
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = ">= 3.10.0"
    }
  }
}

variable "zone" {
  type        = string
  description = "The DNS zone name which will be added, e.g. example.com."
}

variable "page_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    page_rule_name = string
    target         = string
    actions = object({
      forwarding_url = optional(object({
        url         = string
        status_code = number
      }))
    })
    priority   = optional(number)
    status     = optional(string)
    depends_on = optional(string)
  }))
  description = "Zone's page rules."
  default     = []
}

//noinspection HILUnresolvedReference
locals {
  page_rule_dependencies = { for p in var.page_rules : p.page_rule_name => p.depends_on if p.depends_on != null }
}

# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/zone
resource "cloudflare_zone" "this" {
  zone = var.zone
}

# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/page_rule
//noinspection HILUnresolvedReference
resource "cloudflare_page_rule" "this" {
  for_each = var.page_rules != null ? { for p in var.page_rules : p.page_rule_name => p } : {}

  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.this.id

  target = each.value.target
  actions {
    //noinspection HILUnresolvedReference
    forwarding_url {
      status_code = each.value.actions.forwarding_url.status_code
      url         = each.value.actions.forwarding_url.url
    }
  }
  priority = each.value.depends_on != null ? cloudflare_page_rule.this[local.page_rule_dependencies[each.key]].priority + 1 : each.value.priority
  status = each.value.status
}

output "page_rule_dependencies" {
  value = local.page_rule_dependencies
}
```

And a configuration that is used to create resources:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.15.0"

  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = ">= 3.10.1"
    }
  }
}

variable "cloudflare_api_token" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}

provider "cloudflare" {
  api_token = var.cloudflare_api_token
}

module "acme_com" {
  source = "./module"
  zone   = "acme.com"
  page_rules = [
    {
      page_rule_name = "page_rule_1"
      target         = "acme.com/url1"
      actions = {
        forwarding_url = {
          status_code = 301
          url         = "https://www.example.com/url1"
        }
      }
      priority = 1
    },
    {
      page_rule_name = "page_rule_2"
      target         = "acme.com/url2"
      actions = {
        forwarding_url = {
          status_code = 301
          url         = "https://www.example.com/url2"
        }
      }
      priority   = 2
      depends_on = "page_rule_1"
    },
    {
      page_rule_name = "page_rule_3"
      target         = "acme.com/url3"
      actions = {
        forwarding_url = {
          status_code = 301
          url         = "https://www.example.com/url3"
        }
      }
      priority   = 3
      depends_on = "page_rule_2"
    }
  ]
}

output "page_rule_dependencies" {
  value = module.acme_com.page_rule_dependencies
}
```

In this particular example, I've added the `depends_on` argument to the `page_rules` variable (don't confuse this argument with the `depends_on` *meta argument*). For the value of the `depends_on` argument, I specified the name of a `page_fule` on which another `page_fule` depends.

Next, I created a local variable `page_rule_dependencies`, the value of which, after calculations, is the following (you can check this yourself by replacing the `priority = each.value.depends_on != null ? cloudflare_page_rule.this[local.page_rule_dependencies[each.key]].priority + 1 : each.value.priority` construct with `priority = each.value.priority` and executing `terraform apply`):

```
page_rule_dependencies = {
  "page_rule_2" = "page_rule_1"
  "page_rule_3" = "page_rule_2"
}
```

Further, in the `priority = each.value.depends_on != null ? cloudflare_page_rule.this[local.page_rule_dependencies[each.key]].priority + 1 : each.value.priority` construct, I refer to the values ​​of the local variable, thereby forming a "reference" to the `page_fule` instance, on which the current instance depends:

1. When creating `page_rule_1`, the value of its argument `priority` = `1`.
2. When creating `page_rule_2`, the value of its argument `priority` = `cloudflare_page_rule.this["page_rule_1"].priority + 1`.
3. When creating `page_rule_3`, the value of its argument `priority` = `cloudflare_page_rule.this["page_rule_2"].priority + 1`.

However, I get an `Error: Cycle: module.acme_com.cloudflare_page_rule.this["page_rule_3"], module.acme_com.cloudflare_page_rule.this["page_rule_2"], module.acme_com.cloudflare_page_rule.this["page_rule_1"]` error.

Either I'm doing something wrong, or it's some kind of Terraform limitation/bug. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

P.S. Resulting graph after `terraform graph -draw-cycles | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg` or `terraform graph -draw-cycles -type=plan | dot -Tsvg > graph-plan.svg` (the same result):

[image]

P.P.S. I use Terraform v1.1.7.

Comment: This is a cyclic dependency error, meaning that you are referencing resources between each other and Terraform is unsure in which order to create them. Try this and see where the cycle comes from: https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/graph#draw-cycles.

Comment: @MarkoE, thanks, but I can't find any useful info in the resulting graph. I've attached the graph to the initial post.

Comment: You need this command: `terraform graph -draw-cycles`. If the error happens during apply, then you need to add `-type=apply` as well.

Comment: The easy way to know this is if you take a look at `priority = each.value.priority > 1 ? cloudflare_page_rule.this[element(var.page_rules[*].page_rule_name, index(var.page_rules[*].priority, each.value.priority - 1))].priority + 1 : each.value.priority`. You cannot reference the resource itself in the resource block where you are creating it. That will create cyclic dependency error.

Comment: @MarkoE, I can't see any difference, I've updated info in the initial post.

Comment: But I don't reference the resource itself in the resource block.

Comment: How are you not referencing the same resource? Inside of the `cloudflare_page_rule` resource block, for priority you are referencing that same resource (which still isn't created) with `cloudflare_page_rule.this[element...`?

Comment: If I reference the resource itself, I get an error: "Error: Self-referential block". And, for example, why doesn't this work: `priority = each.value.priority > 1 ? cloudflare_page_rule.this["page_rule_1"].priority + each.value.priority : each.value.priority`? in this case for `page_rule_1` which has `priority` equal `1` should be  `each.value.priority` applied, but in this case I get the error: "Error: Self-referential block".  Doesn't Terraform allow the resource itself to be referenced in expressions for that resource at all, even if the expression doesn't apply to it?