# Create AWS_API_GATEWAY_RESOURCES in a loop

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to create the aws_api_gateway resources using terraform, to avoid the hassle of adding the same code again and again, am trying to create a loop which create multiple resources for me in the order i specify. But, I am facing difficulties as I am new to this and it is always complaining of cyclic dependency.

The cyclic dependency is caused in "parent_id" while creating resources

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have coded:

```
locals {
  api_endpoints = [
    {
      path           = "v0"
      http_method    = "GET"
      integration_uri = "${uri_path}/v0"
    },
    {
      path           = "v0/expert/gen/btags"
      http_method    = "POST"
      integration_uri = "${uri_path}/v0/expert/gen/btags"
    },
    {
      path           = "v0/expert/generate/tags"
      http_method    = "POST"
      integration_uri = "${uri_path}/v0/expert/gen/tags"
    },
    {
      path           = "v0/expert/search"
      http_method    = "POST"
      integration_uri = "${uri_path}/v0/expert/search"
    },
  ]
  resources_hierarchy = {
      "v0" = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gatewayh.root_resource_id
      "expert" = "v0"
      "gen" = "expert"
      "search" = "expert"
      "btags" = "gen"
      "tags" = "gen"
    }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api_resource" {
  for_each = local.resources_hierarchy

  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gatewayh.id
  parent_id   = each.value == aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gatewayh.root_resource_id ? each.value : aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource[each.value].id
  path_part   = each.key
}
```

Comment: There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71498535/1198321) (unanswered) that seems closely related to yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full Amazon API Gateway schema is challenging to construct dynamically in Terraform because it ends up requiring resources that depend on themselves. Dependencies in Terraform are between `resource` blocks as a whole rather than the individual instances of them, because Terraform must evaluate `for_each` or `count` before knowing which instances exist and those expressions can themselves have dependencies.

However, you can avoid that problem by using the OpenAPI-based method for describing your API, which follows a flat structure similar to what you've shown as your input. The API Gateway API internally transforms that into the corresponding individual resources, resource methods, integration methods, etc, so the result is the same but constructed in a way that doesn't involve as many resources and doesn't involve any dependencies between the objects.

For example:

```
locals {
  api_ops_by_path = tomap({
    for op in local.api_endpoints : op.path => op
  })
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  # ...

  body = jsonencode({
    openapi = "3.0.1"
    info = {
      title   = "example"
      version = "1.0"
    }
    paths = {
      for path, ops in local.api_ops_by_path : path => {
        for op in ops : lower(op.http_method) => {
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
            httpMethod = op.http_method
            uri        = op.integration_uri
            # ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The above uses `for` expressions to derive a data structure that follows the OpenAPI spec for describing methods associated with paths, and uses the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` extension, specific to Amazon API Gateway, to describe what each operation integrates with. It then uses `jsonencode` to encode that resulting data structure into a form that API Gateway can parse and analyze.

When you define an API Gateway REST API with a `body` argument, you don't need to use any other resources to describe the schema; the information in `body` describes the same tree of resources in a different way. You will still need resources for the deployment, stages, etc, though, because they are independent of the actual API definition.

OpenAPI uses a flat structure -- all paths listed together as a single map, rather than resources nested inside one another -- and so that's a better fit both for the way your input data is structured and for describing this in a form that doesn't cause problems for Terraform's dependency graph.

---

References:

- [`aws_api_gateway_rest_api` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api) in the `hashicorp/aws` provider (and in particular, [the OpenAPI example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api#openapi-specification))
- [Configuring a REST API using OpenAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-import-api.html): Amazon's own docs on how to use OpenAPI to define an API Gateway REST API. The Terraform provider is just wrapping this functionality from the underlying system.
- [Amazon's extensions to OpenAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html), which describe the extra properties you can set in your OpenAPI schema that define the "integration" side of the API, which is not normally part of a standard OpenAPI definition.
- [Terraform's `jsonencode` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode)
- [`for` expressions in Terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for), which allow you to project collection values from one shape to another, so you can reshape your input into a valid OpenAPI schema as API Gateway requires.

Comment: Thanks! this sounds promising, can you provide me some reference links which i can use to write this for my requirement

Comment: This helped but again stuck with one more cyclic dependency. Now i am able to create endpoints but i also need to attach custom lambda authorizer. @martin Can you help me with this

Comment: I imagine what you've created is now pretty different than what you originally shared when you asked this question, so I would suggest starting a new Stack Overflow question that describes what you've written so far and full details on what new problem you've encountered. I look for Terraform questions on here relatively often so I'll probably see your new question once you've posted it, but someone else might also answer first. 

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was able to figure that out myself. This answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible in Terraform.

In a Terraform state, objects depend on resources, not on instances of resources.

You're using `aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource[each.value].id` as an input.

Had you used it as an input in another resource, the dependency would be created on `aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource`, not on a particular instance of `aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource`.

Since a resource cannot depend on itself, Terraform throws the error you're seeing.